# How to give a fixed Uid to my Action

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-7.6.x

Hy,
I'm trying to call my action with allways a fixed Uid (configured by TS) so I could put a plugin on my page to register for a specific Event. And don't have to go over a Event List click the Event click register.

I tried the following which did not work out:

```
public function newAction(
    \XYZ\xyz\Domain\Model\Registration $newRegistration = NULL, 
    \XYZ\xyz\Domain\Model\Event $event = 'DD8B2164290B40DA240D843095A29904'
)
```

The next didn't one work either!

```
public function newAction(
    \XYZ\xyz\Domain\Model\Registration $newRegistration = NULL, 
    \XYZ\xyz\Domain\Model\Event $event = Null
) {
    $myinstance = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(
        'XYZ\\xyz\\Domain\\Model\\Event'
    );
    $event = $myinstance->findByUid('DD8B2164290B40DA240D843095A29904');

    .......
}
```

So I was woundering is there a way to give my fixed Uid to the action?

Comment: In TYPO3 tables the UID is an integer value. Where did you get this kind of string? This can't be the UID.

Comment: Well the events aren't inside Typo3 it's from an source outside.
But I checked the Uid on the Detail Page and its inside the URL as well.     http://example.com/xyz.html?tx_xyz_event%5Bevent%5D=DD8B2164290B40DA240D843095A29904&tx_xyz_event%5Baction%5D=new&tx_xyz_event%5Bcontroller%5D=Registration

Comment: Then you need to overwrite the `findByUid()` function because Extbase checks if the UID is an integer.

Comment: Please do not override the `findByUid` method since it has a dedicated meaning already. Instead, implement a new method e.g. `findByIdentifier(string $identifier)` in the custom `EventRepository`

Answer (score 1):

In TYPO3 calling Extbase actions is done in the routing and dispatching components - to pass anything from the outside that is different from a numeric `uid` value a custom property `TypeConverter` would have to be implemented that transforms a particular string pattern into a value domain object of type `Event`.

However, there's a simpler approach by using configuration:

#### 1) Provide configuration in TypoScript

Extbase uses a strong naming convention based on the extension name and optionally the plugin name. Thus, either `tx_myextension` or `tx_myextension_someplugin` can be used - latter is more specific for for according `somePlugin`. Besides that `settings` are automatically forwarded and provided in an Extbase controller context - accessible by `$this->settings`.

```
plugin.tx_xyz {
  settings {
    newActionEventIdentifier = DD8B2164290B40DA240D843095A29904
  }
}
```

#### 2) Retrieve data via repository

\XYZ\xyz\Domain\Repository\EventRepository

Use a dedicated `EventRepository::findByIdentifier(string)` method to retrieve the data. The property names are just assumptions since there are no explicit mentions how exactly the event data is persisted and whether it is persisted in a relational DBMS at all.

```
<?php
namespace XYZ\xyz\Domain\Repository;
class EventRepository
{
    public function findByIdentifier($identifier)
    {
        $query = $this->createQuery();
        $query->matching(
            $query->equals('event_id', $identifier)
        );
        return $query->execute();
    }
}
```

#### 3) Putting all together in the according controller

The `$event` property was removed from the action since that entity is pre-defined and cannot be submitted from the outside (and to support the string to `Event` entity transformation a custom `TypeConverter` would be required as mentioned earlier).

```
public function newAction(
    \XYZ\xyz\Domain\Model\Registration $newRegistration = null
) {
    $event = $this->eventRepository->findByIdentifier(
        $this->settings['newActionEventIdentifier']
    );
    if ($event === null) {
        throw new \RuntimeException('No event found', 1522070079);
    }
    // the regular controller tasks
    $this->view->assign(...);
}
```

Comment: Thank you.
I'll try that. But I guess I'll haveing a hard time figuring out how to get the Data in my repository as the plugin allready gets the right Data if I'm comming List View/Deatil View/Registration.

Comment: (quote from one of your comments to the initial question)
`Well the events aren't inside Typo3 it's from an source outside. But I checked the Uid on the Detail Page and its inside the URL as well.`
Okay, where is the data coming from then, if it's not managed within TYPO3?